# Whey I have a problem to identify a class on javascript

Tags: javascript, class, eslint, jslint

I create a JavaScript `class` like below:

```
class contact{
   constructeur(nom,prenom){
     this.nom = nom;
     this.prenom = prenom;
   }     

   function afficher(){
     return "Nom : " + this.nom + "Prenom : " + this.prenom;
   }

...
```

But I have an error in jslint `Excepted an identifier saw 'class'`

And in eslint gives an error on `the keyword 'Class' is reserved`

Comment: is the function supposed to be inside the class?

Comment: Did you enabled ES6 syntax in ESLint? There should be an option `ecmaVersion`

Comment: The class' constructor should also be spelt in English, not a foreign language.

Comment: Yes I did I have already the option ecmaVersion in toolbar

Comment: @Addis Yes that

Comment: Crockford (jslint's author) does not approve of the use of classes. Full stop. You can check [the instructions](https://jslint.com/help.html#es6) for what he does allow. Addis' answer (plus ema's hint) works for me; is there a reason you haven't accepted that answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. as [ema says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671522/whey-i-have-a-problem-to-identify-a-class-on-javascript#comment105501928_59671522), you need esversion set to 6.
2. class names should start with block letters, even though this may not be a cause for an error message.
3. `constructor` is misspelled
4. you don't need `function` keyword for class methods.

```
/*jshint esversion:6 */

class Contact {
  constructor (nom, prenom) {
      this.nom = nom;
      this.prenom = prenom;
  }
  afficher () {
      return "Nom : " + this.nom + " Prenom : " + this.prenom;
  }
}
```